# how can I add component elements as dynamic component into child component in vue3

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

**I want to make data grid component in vue3**

But the problem is, for different type of data, I need to add different type of action buttons.

Please see the image bellow, I have described in the photo, what I want.

Please advice me.

[image: My code structure is]

Codes zip link given below:

[**Click here to get code**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O-yupYHslDFVjKZuyXzyPwPacQ-ZDp5r/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: please share also the code

Comment: What you are looking for is the slots, [scoped slots](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-slots.html#scoped-slots) in particular

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim code added

Comment: @MichalLevý may I get an example?

Comment: @MichalLevý , thank you so much, it works using scoped slots